# Instructions inside brackets that has only Static keyword as header

Tags: java, static

I have tried to find an answer about this specificity but can not find any.

I have in the code below an instruction inside brackets that has only the `static` keyword as header.

I do understand clearly what it does and could guess their use just like any of the other `static` methods/variables but I can not put a name on it.

It's not a variable nor a method (it does not return anything, not even "`void`") and certainly not a constructor since the `static` keyword is used.

What do we call this type of special "methods"?

Here is the code :

```
    public class Test{

    static {
        System.out.println("What do we call this?");
    }

    public Test(){
        System.out.println("Instance of Test created");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSon().go();
    }

    public void go(){
        System.out.println("Go method Test");
    }

}

class TestSon extends Test{

    static {
        System.out.println("Same here...");
    }

    public TestSon(){
        System.out.println("Instance of TestSon created");
    }

    @Override
    public void go() {
        System.out.println("Go method son");
    }
}
```

The output :

```
What do we call this?
Same here...
Instance of Test created
Instance of TestSon created
Go method son
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a so called 'static initialization block' you can read more about it at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1):

It is called an initializer block, it can be static (once per class) or not, for initialization per object instance.

A typical usage:

```
public A {

    static final Map<String, String> TRANSLATIONS = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        TRANSLATUIBS.put("un", "one");
        TRANSLATUIBS.put("deux", "two");
        TRANSLATUIBS.put("trois", "three");
    }

    final URL MY_HOME_PAGE;
    {
         try {
             MY_HOME_PAGE = new URL("...");
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             throw new IllegalStateException();
         ]
    }
```

For a non-static initializer, the code have been placed in a constructor.

The static initializer is called at the first usage of the class. So it is not necessarily called if the class is not used.